# Tem como capturar um value do radio button via ajax

Tags: ajax

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle col-xs-5" data-toggle="buttons">
            <button type="radio" name="tipoTransacao" id="tipoTransacao" value="1" class="btn btn-success" ><i class='fa fa-arrow-up'></i>Entrada</button>
            <button type="radio" name="tipoTransacao" id="tipoTransacao" value="2" class="btn btn-danger">Saída<i class='fa fa-arrow-down'></i>Saída</button>
          </div>
```

e estou tentando fazer a captura assim:

```
function salvar(e){
e.preventDefault();
var fk_idConta = $(this).find('select[name=fk_idConta]').val();

var tipoTransacao =  $("button[name='tipoTransacao']:checked").val();
var demo8 = $(this).find('input[name=demo8]').val();
var dataTransacao = $(this).find('input[name=dataTransacao]').val();
var meioTransacao = $("input[name='meioTransacao']:checked").val();
var descTransacao = $(this).find('textarea[name=descTransacao]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Elementos `<button>` não possuem `value`. Mesmo que você declare os valores no HTML, eles não existirão no JavaScript. A forma "correta" de se utilizar radio buttons, é dar `name` diferentes para eles, e então validar pelo nome, não pelo valor.

Porém, se você absolutamente precisa trabalhar dessa forma, você pode pegar o valor de `value` diretamente do atributo declarado no HTML com `$("button[name='tipoTransacao']:checked").attr('value')`